# Android Studio hangs when an exception is thrown in external library

Tags: android, android-studio, freeze

I am having an issue with Android Studio (3.1.3) where the application will hang when (what i assume is) an exception is thrown from within an external library. It makes it impossible to debug since I never get to see what the exception is. It isn't printed into Logcat, the debug console and the exception isn't being caught inside of a try catch statement.

At first I thought it was because the code was running on another thread, but it happens when it is running on the main thread as well.

I also tried restarting the emulator, android studio, and my computer, but none of them helped.

It doesn't happen for all exceptions (I testing by trying to divide by 0)

If it helps this is the code that is throwing the exception:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new InterfaceAdapter()).create();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(getFileName(context), ContextWrapper.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
try {           
    String value = gson.toJson(user); //this is where the program hangs
    editor.putString(getKeyName(), value);
    editor.apply();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is basically what logcat looks like right after the issue starts:

> 07-26 08:28:06.754 6211-6220/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=76KB, data=76KB
>
> 07-26 08:28:06.756 6211-6220/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=42KB, data=44KB
>
> 07-26 08:28:14.867 6211-6224/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Debugger
>
> 07-26 08:28:14.883 6211-6224/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 16.146ms for cause Debugger
>
> 07-26 08:28:15.201 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 409390(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 41(984KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 18MB/24MB, paused 692us total 101.606ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:15.519 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 592391(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 48(1428KB) LOS objects, 18% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 799us total 124.258ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:15.718 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 668826(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 47(1520KB) LOS objects, 15% free, 31MB/37MB, paused 1.041ms total 149.078ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:15.933 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 781317(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 51(1836KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 37MB/43MB, paused 1.114ms total 169.812ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:16.172 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 871622(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 52(2044KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 43MB/49MB, paused 1.219ms total 192.129ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:16.461 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 985287(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 55(2MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 49MB/55MB, paused 962us total 239.343ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:16.799 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1046427(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 52(2MB) LOS objects, 9% free, 58MB/64MB, paused 1.088ms total 290.110ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:17.121 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1235281(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 58(2MB) LOS objects, 8% free, 65MB/71MB, paused 924us total 281.931ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:17.512 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1305931(22MB) AllocSpace objects, 58(2MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 76MB/82MB, paused 2.252ms total 347.833ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:17.946 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1545721(25MB) AllocSpace objects, 62(3MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 86MB/92MB, paused 670us total 388.329ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:18.446 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1689093(28MB) AllocSpace objects, 64(3MB) LOS objects, 5% free, 94MB/100MB, paused 811us total 447.255ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:18.993 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1706872(28MB) AllocSpace objects, 61(3MB) LOS objects, 5% free, 106MB/112MB, paused 1.647ms total 494.095ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:19.564 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1917145(31MB) AllocSpace objects, 64(4MB) LOS objects, 4% free, 124MB/130MB, paused 1.588ms total 525.774ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:19.869 6211-6224/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Debugger
>
> 07-26 08:28:20.215 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 2316750(38MB) AllocSpace objects, 73(5MB) LOS objects, 4% free, 138MB/144MB, paused 675us total 594.107ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:20.215 6211-6224/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 345.610ms for cause Debugger
>
> 07-26 08:28:20.921 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 2507776(41MB) AllocSpace objects, 74(5MB) LOS objects, 4% free, 136MB/142MB, paused 711us total 657.115ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:21.698 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1960643(32MB) AllocSpace objects, 55(4MB) LOS objects, 3% free, 170MB/176MB, paused 2.113ms total 729.245ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:22.563 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 3069424(50MB) AllocSpace objects, 82(6MB) LOS objects, 3% free, 191MB/197MB, paused 2.610ms total 817.861ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:23.553 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 3358701(55MB) AllocSpace objects, 84(7MB) LOS objects, 3% free, 188MB/194MB, paused 2.265ms total 941.755ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:24.550 6211-6228/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 2638191(43MB) AllocSpace objects, 63(5MB) LOS objects, 2% free, 227MB/233MB, paused 687us total 939.390ms
>
> 07-26 08:28:24.869 6211-6224/org.myorg.myapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Debugger

Comment: can you show us what are user object and getKeyname() return value

Comment: @masoudvali I actually just figure out the bug when I went to copy the code (It was from storing a context object as part of the class (I had to make it transient). However, I still don't know why Android Studio hangs and thats what the question is really about

Answer (score 0):

Go to your logcat, on the right side there will be a spinner with options how to filter logs. Choose Edit Filter Configuration and type your package name. That way you'll be able to trace logs, that are vanishing in your case.

[image]

Cheers!